# ServletContext#getRealPath(File.separator) giveing null in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, realpath

I use following code in HttpServlet.

```
String pathToWeb = getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);
```

I have application where above code is working fine and return the real path of application directory. Whereas I send another branch for QA and not able to detect the real-path using above code.

which is always return null, using java8,tomcat8 on windows server. 
Please assist.

I already gone through question like this but not able to find out the solution.

Comment: @wero, the path to application folder.

Comment: @wero, yes I am on windows server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/` for the path of the context root:

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
```

instead of the OS-specific file separator.